# groupby list in python, how to only show the amount of an item value when item value > 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in python that handles all of the items a user has in my text rpg game. I am using the groupby module to group multiple instances of an item together and then writing the amount in parenthesis next to the item when I print the list. the code is below:

```
item_inventory["sword", "sword", "jelly", "egg"]

item_list = groupby(sorted(item_inventory))

for k, g in item_list:
        print(k, "(" + str(sum(1 for _ in g)) + ")")
```

the output looks like this:

```
egg (1)
jelly (1)
sword (2)
```

however I would only want the quantity to show up if there is more than one in the list, with a result like this:

```
egg 
jelly 
sword (2)
```

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
for k, g in item_list:
    if sum(1 for _ in g) > 1:
        print(k, "(" + str(sum(1 for _ in g)) + ")")
    else:
        print(k)
```

all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your exhausting the iterable the first time you use it (in `sum(1 for _ in g) > 1`), this should fix it:

```
from itertools import groupby

item_inventory = ["sword", "sword", "jelly", "egg"]

item_list = groupby(sorted(item_inventory))

for k, g in item_list:
    count = sum(1 for _ in g)
    if count > 1:
        print(k, "(" + str(count) + ")")
    else:
        print(k)
```

**Output**

```
egg
jelly
sword (2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear response. It worked very easily. I knew it was just a quick fix. I am still a beginner so I miss some of these things! thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` may be more useful for this problem:

```
from collections import Counter
for item,count in Counter(item_inventory).items():
    print('{}{}'.format(item, '' if count==1 else " ({})".format(count)))
#sword (2)
#jelly 
#egg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a list from the grouped values and check its lenght:

```
from itertools import groupby

item_inventory = ["sword", "sword", "jelly", "egg"]
item_list = groupby(sorted(item_inventory))

def format_me(items):
    l = list(items)
    return "" if len(l) == 1 else "({})".format(len(l))

for k, g in item_list: 
    print(k, format_me(g))
```

This will print:

```
egg 
jelly 
sword (2)
```